# The derivative as a ratio

Tags: differential

As $$\frac{dy}{dx}= \lim_{∆x \to 0}\frac{∆y}{∆x}$$ then why $$\frac{dy}{dx}$$ is not a ratio ?

Comment: It is a number, because the "limit of the ratio..." is defined to be a *real* number.

Comment: A ratio of what to what?

Comment: What do you mean by a ratio? Every number is a ratio with denominator one.

Comment: I think you can think of it as a ratio. It is the "rate of change" in y with respect to change in x. Also if you have dy/dx=x, for instance, you could write it as dy=x.dx, integrating both sides, you get: y+c1=x2/2 + c2. You could also consider it as symbol as in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{dy}{dx}$ is simply (Leibnitz) notation for the derivative. It is a symbol, like $y'$, $y'(x)$, and so forth.